# In rails 3.1 how does this coffee script effect things? Is it easy to opt out of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

If I upgrade my existing rails 3 app to 3.1, will it cause any issues with coffeescript?

How can I opt out and have things run as 'normal'?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be affected, as all .js files are left alone. Only .coffee files are parsed by CoffeeScript.

Thus, you can experiment with CoffeeScript while at the same time leaving all existing javascript code alone.

Answer (score 2):

To turn coffescript thing 'off' just delete or uncomment `gem 'coffee-script'` line in Gemfile.